# error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [8]’ and ‘const char [7]’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting the following error:

error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [8]’ and ‘const char [7]’ to binary ‘operator<<’

with the following code. Any idea why?

## main.cpp

```
#include <sstream>      // std::stringstream

#define logStream(MSG) _logStream(MSG)

void _logStream(std::string MSG)
{ 
    std::stringstream _trace_stream_;
    _trace_stream_ << "logStream: " << MSG << std::endl;
}  

int main()
{
    logStream("Hello, " << "world!");    // compile error here

    return 0;
}
```

However there is no compilation error when inline logStream macro is used.

```
#include <sstream> // std::stringstream

#define logStream(MSG) { \ 
    std::stringstream trace_stream; \ 
    trace_stream << "logStream: " << MSG << std::endl; \ 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    logStream("Hello, " << "world!"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

why?

Comment: Because the argument to `logStream` is a *string* and not a stream.

Comment: the `operator<<` you're trying to use is for streams, not strings

Comment: What do you expect `"Hello, " << "world!"` on its own would do? Your code has no defined binary `operator<<` for two `const char[]`

Comment: Maybe you wanted `MSG` to be substituted by the supplied expression? Then you need a macro, not a function

Comment: @KABoissonneault: He already tried that, `logStream` is a macro :D

Comment: Judging by the name, maybe this is what you're going for? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b2d6d34a67b0c33

Comment: Oddly enough `"Hello, "  "world!"`, without the `<<` will work for concatenating two string literals.

Comment: The << will work when logStream is just an inline macro as follows:#include <sstream> // std::stringstream #define logStream(MSG) { \ std::stringstream trace_stream; \ trace_stream << MSG << std::endl; \ } int main() { logStream("Hello, " << "world!"); return 0; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> logStream("Hello, " << "world!")
> ```

There is no overload of `operator<<` for the case that **both arguments are string literals** (aka `const char[n]`).

There is an overload of `operator<<` for the case that **one of the arguments is a stream**. But the stream is only created inside your function `logStream()`. It is not available yet when you pass the argument to the function.

To solve the issue of combining multiple values for logging, you can use `operator+` of `std::string`:

```
logStream(std::string("Hello, ") + "world!");
```

Similarly if one of the arguments is a number:

```
logStream(std::string("Hello, ") + "world " + std::to_string(42) + "!" );
```

This questions is not tagged C++14, but this is how you could add some syntactic sugar by using the new [string literal operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
logStream("Hello, "s + "world!");
```

Answer (score 0):

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) said, you can't concatenate strings using operator<< (unless you write your own overload), but your program still has undefined behaviour. Quote from c++14 standard:

> 17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to
>   the implementation:
>
> — Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an
>   underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the
>   implementation for any use.
>
> **— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the
>   implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.**